# iReport + PHP + Passagem de Valor Input

Tags: php, input, ireport

Estou com dúvida, eu preciso emitir um relatório específico.
Preciso pegar um nome digitado por um campo de input, e gerar o relatório através desse nome, dei uma pesquisada sobre parâmetros, e não entendi muito bem como fazer. Alguém sabe como fazer?

Nome: 
                            
                            

                            Pesquisar

Comment: para passar o parâmetro ou para o iReport receber o parâmetro?

Comment: para o iReport receber o parametro passado pelo campo input